# Package "fontconfig" not found despite having installed libfontconfig1-dev

Tags: configure, fontconfig, apt-file

Whilst attempting to compile [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org) from source I get the error `Package "fontconfig" not found`.

I have found a lot of other resources advertising that this can be fixed by installing both `pkg-config` and `libfontconfig1-dev` to get the libraries, but I still got the error.

Trying to install `fontconfig` from source failed at the `make` step and I've found no resources on how to fix (whole host of C errors).

If I have `fontconfig` on the system (and `apt` seems to suggest I do) how can I use it when running `./configure` for a package?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key here turned out to be the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. This was empty on a standard shell session on my system.

There seem to be lots of directories with `pkgconfig` in the name, but to find the correct one I was able to use apt-file per this thread i.e.

`$ apt-file search fontconfig.pc
libfontconfig1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/fontconfig.pc`

Then run

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`

And now the `./configure` step can find the `.pc` file which it requires for that library. Learning about `apt-file` seems to be a useful outcome of this problem.

Answer (score 19):

Whenever you get messages about missing packages (or suggestions to modify your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`) during a build, it usually indicates that you are missing the corresponding *development* package - which is typically separate from the runtime package that is normally installed on the system.

In this case you have the most recent version of `fontconfig` but are probably missing the corresponding `libfontconfig1-dev` package.

src: https://askubuntu.com/questions/536714/autogen-sh-cant-find-fontconfig-package

Comment: In the question: “this can be fixed by installing both pkg-config and libfontconfig1-dev to get the libraries, but I still got the error.”

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: On Centos 7 I needed to `yum -y install fontconfig-devel` to get the missing dependency. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, apt-file claimed I had it. A look at the directory showed it wasn't there. I ran "sudo apt-get install libfontconfig-dev" and then it was there.

Comment: Solved my problem. Just didn't have the dev version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits. I got this error while compiling the NAEV game and I looked at the answers listed here.

I searched for `fontconfig.pc`, it was found and I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the proper path, to no avail.

`libfontconfig1-dev` was actually listed as installed.

After looking at other sites, I however re-ran `sudo apt-get install libfontconfig-dev` to be sure, it told me it would actually install `libfontconfig1-dev`, so I confirmed. Then I unset `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to be sure to test in the original configuration, and ran `./configure` : it worked.

So my answer for such errors is the following : **even if your system says the missing package is installed and finds the `pc` file, reinstall it by the book, there might be a glitch somewhere reinstall can fix...**

Answer (score 2):

Installing `libfontconfig1-dev` solved the issue for me.

```
sudo apt install libfontconfig1-dev
```